# If B2 in sheet 1 matches any cell on sheet 3, copy the next cell from sheet 3. (copying to sheet 1)

Tags: excel

Anyone who could give me the excel formula for this? Thank you!

If B2 in sheet 1 matches any cell from column A of Sheet 3, copy the cell found on the right of that (column B).

Copying to a cell in sheet 1.

Thanks! (I hope this isn't too confusing.)

For example B2 is "8 December". Then there is a list of dates on Column A of Sheet 3. On column B of sheet 3 is a corresponding time. So for example, on the right of 8 December on Sheet 3 is 8:30, I want that to be copied on the cell I'm making a formula on.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you can, please try to make the title of your question more concise, in your case it is mainly a repetition of your question. Also it is always appreciated if you show that (and what) you already tried to solve the problem yourself rather than simply asking the community to do the work for you ( see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more hints on how to ask good questions )

Comment: I don't know how to make this any more concise. And yes, I searched  for a long time but couldn't find the answer. Trying to make it more concise: On B2 sheet 1, there will be a date. If it matches a date on column A of sheet 3, I want the corresponding time, which is saved on the cell to the right of that cell to be copied to this cell on sheet 1 I'll use the formula on. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @pnuts items on column A of sheet 3 are dates so nope, there won't be two or more matches.

Comment: Please refer to the additional info I posted. Edited my original post. Thanks a lot, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some folk use the `LOOKUP` function for this, but I like to use `MATCH` and `INDEX` because it gives you more freedom for more advanced formula (such as checking if there was a match or not) and has less requirements (such as data doesn't need to be sorted).

```
=INDEX(Sheet3!B:B, MATCH(Sheet1!B2, Sheet3!A:A, 0))
```

If you break it down into the parts, `MATCH(Sheet1!B2, Sheet3!A:A, 0)` returns the row number for the **first** matching cell in column A of sheet Sheet3.  Then `INDEX(Sheet3!B:B, ...)` returns the value of the cell in column B of sheet Sheet3 at a specified row number.

If nothing matched, then you'll get a `#NA` error value.

Comment: Thanks so much, Miss Yu! How about if I want to subtract 30 minutes from the value that comes up? =INDEX(Sheet3!B:B, MATCH(Sheet1!B2, Sheet3!A:A, 0))-TIME (0,30,0) doesn't work. Thanks again!

Comment: Nothing in the formula I provided should prevent that. If you receive a `#N/A` result, then there was no match, so Excel had nothing to subtract from. If you receive a `#VALUE!` result, then it means Excel doesn't think the values on Sheet3 are proper times. Try using one of the cells on Sheet3 directly, for instance `=Sheet3!B2-TIME(0,30,0)`; does it have the same problem? If so, then it's not an issue of the index-match. Sometimes it's just a format issue and wrapping the result in a `VALUE()` function can fix it, like so `=VALUE(INDEX(Sheet3!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!B2,Sheet3!A:A,0)))-TIME(0,30,0)`

Comment: Thank you so much, Miss Yu. It worked. :) You're really helpful!